# removed devices still appear as attached

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, centos-7, umount

Linux, Centos 7

I removed USB hard drives from my machine.

They are `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`.

I think they were not properly umounted before removal.

I have since tried to umount them (also with `-l`).

They still show as attached devices.

Plugging them back in makes no difference; I monitored `/var/log/messages` and there is no response from the machine.

```
[root@linux18 ~]# lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                    8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                    8:2    0   931G  0 part 
  ├─centos_linux18-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos_linux18-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
**sdb                       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                    8:17   0   1.8T  0 part 
sdc                       8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdc1                    8:33   0   1.8T  0 part** 
sdd                       8:48   1   1.9G  0 disk 
└─sdd1                    8:49   1   1.9G  0 part /run/media/michael/Lexar
sde                       8:64   0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sde1                    8:65   0  98.6G  0 part 
└─sde2                    8:66   0 134.3G  0 part 
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: I presume you have tried to reboot the system?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I am hoping not to need to do reboot, but will if necessary.

Comment: I rebooted and now the devices no longer appear. Thank you. I was looking for a way not to reboot, but that solved it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a restart/reboot? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about CentOS, but on Ubuntu you can run partprobe to cause it to rescan the bus. After doing that, it is no longer listed.